# bash terminate on first fail

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to make my bash script terminates on the first command that returns non-zero status?

I know I can just chain it with `&&`'s like:

```
cd /stuff &&
echo 'what's up' &&
....
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is *that* simple as adding at the beginning of your script after the *shebang* :

```
set -e
```

You can stop this if you want (for just a portion of code) with

```
set +e
```

or on the *shebang* :

```
#!/bin/bash -e
```

or by calling the script with :

```
bash -e script.bash
```